# Express $\frac x{x^2-3x + 2}$ in the partial fraction form and show that its partial fraction $x^3$ can be neglected

Tags: binomial-theorem, partial-fractions

I am having trouble solving a multi part question.

Express $ \frac x{x^2-3x + 2} $ in the partial fraction form.

The answer I got was $\frac2{x-2}-\frac1{x-1}$ .

The problem comes when they asked:

Show that, if $x$ is so small that $x^3$ and higher powers of $x$ can be neglected, then:

$$\frac x{x^2-3x +2}\approx\frac12x+\frac34x^2$$

I understand that I had to expand the partial fraction using Generalized Binomial Theorem such that I needed to expand: $-\left[1+\left(-\frac12x\right)\right]^{-1}+\left[1+\left(-x\right)\right]^{-1}$ since I needed to manipulate the equation into $\left(1+a\right)^n$ format.

I got $$\frac12x+\frac34x^2+\frac78x^3+\frac{15}{16}x^4+\cdots$$

but I am not sure how to continue to **show that , if $x$ is so small that $x^3$ and higher powers of $x$ can be neglected**. Do i just sub in numbers ranging from -1 to 1 and that's it or is there a structured way to show?

Comment: Does the underscore _ means + ?

Comment: @Rzu Yes, sorry edited!

Comment: Neglected means "replaced with 0". What happens if you replace the powers in your series $x^3$ and abovewith $0$?

Comment: As an aside, I really don't understand the close vote here. Things were written out clearly, work done was shown, and thoughts/guesses were provided as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are already done and just have linguistic issue; I think that "if $x$ is so small that $x^3$ and higher powers of $x$ can be neglected, then [...]" should be interpreted as "if $x$ has property $P(x)$, then [...]" where $P(x)\equiv$ "$x^3$ and higher powers can be neglected". That is, you are not supposed to show that you can neglect $x^3$, it's an assumption. Thus, it's the same question as "show that power series expansion is $x/2 + 3x^2/4\, + $ higher order terms."

Comment: If it is like what you explained, I would have solved the question! :)

Comment: @deviljones, you said you got the correct expansion. I'd call it solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just cross out terms with $x^3$, $x^4$, ... in the approximation.

The question assumes these terms are too small, and we don't care.

For example, if I know x is between 0 and 0.1. Then $x^3$ is at most 0.001. $x^4$ is even smaller.

I think the sum of the terms $x^3$, $x^4$, ... are at least smaller than $x^2$, which is at most 0.01.

I forget the exact formula for the errors. I just use sum of a geometric series and approximate the coefficient of all terms as 1.

Let's say an error of 0.02 is acceptable in the approximation.

I would use just the $x$ and $x^2$ terms in that case.

Less terms means a computer program can approximate the thing faster.

Comment: The difference isn't that huge. Problem is I don't know how to show, do I show that when i sub $x$ = 0.1 from $x$ to $x^2$ vs from $x$ to $x^4$ the difference isn't huge therefore I can ignore $x^3$ and above?

Comment: The problem didn't specify a range for $x$. It just says suppose you can neglect (ignore) the 3rd and higher order terms. So you use that as a reason to cross out those terms in the approximation.

Comment: In other words, I can just interpret it as expand to coefficients to $x^2$ to put it simply?

Comment: The thing equals to your expansion with the ... In the next line, write an approximation sign $\approx$, cross out the extra terms, and I would be too lazy to write any more things. If you want, explain that since the problem says the higher order terms can be neglected, they are crossed out in the approximation.

Comment: okay, I got it, thank you :)